# Spring batch using partitioning some threads hangs

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spring-batch

we are using Spring Batch v2.1.9 on top of a Grails application to process 100k transactions every day. One step of this batch job has to read those transactions from a MongoDB, process them by making a couple of REST calls and changing the status, and finally saves them back on the MongoDB. This particular step is using local partitioner to try to improve the speed of the execution, is now using 100 threads on grid-size. The thing is that some times several slave steps just get stuck and does not continue and leaving the job on a state that cannot even be restarted.
My master and slave step configuration is like this:

```
batch.step(id: 'rulesMaster', next: 'filesBuilder') {
   batch.partition(step: 'jerseyRulesSlave', partitioner: 'rangePartitioner') {
        batch.handler('grid-size': 100, 'task-executor': 'taskExecutor')
   }
   batch.listeners {
        batch.listener(ref: "rulesStepConfigsLoaderListener")
   }
}

taskExecutor(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor)

batch.step(id: 'rulesSlave') {
    batch.tasklet {
        batch.chunk(
            reader: 'transactionItemReader',
            processor: 'transactionProcessor',
            writer: 'transactionWriter',
            'commit-interval': 200
        )
    }
}
```

We use MySQL for Spring Batch to run, and on BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION we have rows like this on COMPLETED status:

```
STEP_EXECUTION_ID=10592, 
VERSION='5',
STEP_NAME='rulesSlave:partition88',
JOB_EXECUTION_ID='2045',
START_TIME='2016-09-30 02:08:19', 
END_TIME='2016-09-30 02:48:38',
STATUS='COMPLETED', 
COMMIT_COUNT='3', 
READ_COUNT= '582', 
FILTER_COUNT='0', 
WRITE_COUNT='582', 
READ_SKIP_COUNT='0', 
WRITE_SKIP_COUNT='0', 
PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT='0', 
ROLLBACK_COUNT='0', 
EXIT_CODE='COMPLETED', 
EXIT_MESSAGE='', 
LAST_UPDATED='2016-09-30 02:48:38'
```

and like this on EXECUTING status:

```
STEP_EXECUTION_ID='10593', 
VERSION='1', 
STEP_NAME='rulesSlave:partition89', 
JOB_EXECUTION_ID='2045', 
START_TIME='2016-09-30 02:08:20', 
END_TIME=NULL, 
STATUS='STARTED', 
COMMIT_COUNT='0', 
READ_COUNT='0', 
FILTER_COUNT='0', 
WRITE_COUNT='0', 
READ_SKIP_COUNT='0', 
WRITE_SKIP_COUNT='0', 
PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT='0', 
ROLLBACK_COUNT='0', 
EXIT_CODE='EXECUTING', 
EXIT_MESSAGE='', 
LAST_UPDATED='2016-09-30 02:08:20'
```

A couple of questions that we have:

- Are we missing something? Is there anything misconfigured?
- Is there any way to update the rows on the Spring batch table by hand to leave the job on a restartable status?
- How can we notice that the slaves steps are stuck so we can raise the alarm?

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated!